# Jquery "$.uniform is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-uniform

I am using uniformjs to style some html element but when i try to update an element such as a check box using

```
$.uniform.update('input[type=checkbox]');
```

I get the error

> $.uniform is undefined

any one else have an idea how to solve this?

I have both jQuery and the uniform.js added to the page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

What's weird is this worked when it was a regular HTML page and stopped working when i made it into a ASP.NET page and added custom form validators. Perhaps there is some clash?

Comment: the plugin `uniform` is not included properly..

Comment: do you have the [uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/) dependencies added to the page

Comment: @Arun P Johny yes i do.

Answer (score 3):

Reason for this error is browser cant identify `$.uniform` which can be because of following two reasons:

- You have not included `uniform.js` file to your page, check if a similar looking lines is present in your markup.

  ```
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.uniform.js"></script>
  ```
- You are referencing it before its been loaded (have you included it at the end of the page, after the markup?)

Comment: I have edited my original post to show my scripts that are added to my page, and all of them are before the markup.

Comment: you are using `jQuery 1.4` which is quite old and as per [uniform.js](http://uniformjs.com/) it `Works well with jQuery 1.6+, but we've received patches and heard that this works with jQuery 1.3.` For a check try upgrading jQuery?

Comment: changed jquery version to 1.8 still the same issue.

Comment: are you sure that `jquery.uniform.js` is picked by the browser meaning the path is correct and its loaded? A basic way to check it is go to the source of the page in browser `Righ Click` -> `View Page Source` find the `<script>` tag where you are referencing `jquery.uniform.js` and click the link inside `src` attribute and see if it open the script or not. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load all your dependencies and the current library itself to make it work.

For your css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uniform.default.css" media="screen" />
```

For your javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.uniform.js"></script>
```

Please, [check this JSFiddle that I've build for you](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/6tBZ4/), showing uniformjs working.